# It is not correct to get the time in the podman container

Tags: shell, date, podman

i use this command to start podman container

```
podman run --name test --rm -ti alpine /bin/sh
```

update  timezone use

```
apk add --no-cache tzdata  &&  ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
```

however i got difference result

in podman container is "2022-11-28_11-05-23"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1w2S.png)

my mac is  "2022-11-28_17-59-03"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zaiM.png)

i want to get correct time ?

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem with this command

```
podman machine ssh sudo date --set $(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

[github issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/11541)